# MIPS check number of elements in array

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to write a program to check the size of two arrays, make sure they are less than a certain value (99), and make sure their sum is also less than a value (99). However, the sum of the two array sizes is being placed into r13 but it is not breaking if the values are greater than 99

```
.data
arrayOne: .word 5 1 3 6 7 8
arrayTwo: .word 3 5 7 9
arrayMerged: .word 99

.text
main:
ld r1, arrayOne(r0) ;load the num elements into r1
ld r2, arrayTwo(r0) ;load the num elements into r2
lui r31, 99
slt r30, r1, r31    ;check to see if r1 is larger than 99
beq r30, r31, l3        ;if r1 is larger than 99, goto l3
slt r30, r2, r31    ;check to see if r2 is larger than 99
beq r30, r31, l3        ;if r2 is larger than 99, goto l3
dadd r13, r1, r2    ;add the sum of r1 and r2 and store in r13
slt r30, r13, r31   ;check to see if the sum of arrayOne and arrayTwo is larger than 99
beq r30, r31, l3        ;if r13 is larger than 99, goto l3

l3: halt
```

Comment: You are using `lui r31,99`, you should be using `li r31,99`.  BUT you should be following the MIPS register usage conventions, in particular `r31` is reserved for the return address of the current routine.

Answer (score 0):

- `r1` and such are not valid register naming. You either want `$1` or `$at` (btw you shouldn't be using register 1, IIRC it is reserved).
- There is no `halt` instruction in MIPS. What you want is a syscall exit.